# Ajax call not replacing the content

Tags: php, html, ajax

What I want to do is replace the content of a div after a log in with a welcome message. I've read AJAX tutorials but I might've got it wrong.

Isn't the logIn function supposed to change the content of the element with the given id, with the content echoed by the php file?

Because right now, the log in is done but the content echoed by the php file is displayed in login.php instead of replacing the content of my "user_panel" div.

**My html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>My awesome blog!</title>

<script>
  function logIn(u,p) {

    if (u== "" && p== "") {
      document.getElementById("user_panel").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }  

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("user_panel").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php?u="+u+"&p="+p,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }

</script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
    <div id="user_panel">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


         <form class="login" action="login.php" method="post">
            <label class="login_label" for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <br>
            <label class="login_label" for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="logIn(document.getElementById('username'),document.getElementById('password'))">
        </form> 


  </body>
</html>
```

**my php**

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "BlogDb";


    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password,$dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //echo "Connected successfully2";

    $u = $_POST['username'];
    $p = $_POST['password'];
    setcookie("User_in", $u, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["user_on"] = $u;

    $sql= "SELECT username,is_admin FROM User WHERE username ='".$u."' and password='".$p."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "Welcome " . $row['username'] . "! How are you today?";
    echo "</li><li>";
    echo "<a href=logout.php>Log out</a>";
    echo "</li></ul>";
  }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ajax wont automaticaly replace the page content.you have to put the response content to some portion of page using js after you get the response back.

Comment: Have you checked developers' console? Any errors there?

Comment: Where you prevent your default form submission action, After clicking on submit button your page will get refresh. Either you can go through the default form submission or Ajax Login (If you want to show the login succeed message without page refresh )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input type='sumbit' when clicked where submit this form so you must prevent this default event you can change this type='button'!

document.getElementById('username') where return node n't input value get input value can use

```
 document.getElementById('username').value
```

below is my change code:
**html:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="logIn()">
```

**js:**

```
function logIn(e) {
    e =  e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();

    var u = document.getElementById('username').value,
        p = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (u== "" && p== "") {
      document.getElementById("user_panel").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }  

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("user_panel").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php?u="+u+"&p="+p,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Alright, but how do I get the values in the script? `$_POST['u']` or somehow else? Because right now, it takes the input and does nothing.

Comment: ***login.php?u="+u+"&p="+p*** you put data in uri so you can use $_GET['u'] to get

Answer (score 0):

*** This is a comment as I don't have access to the comment section I am adding as answer******
Hi Matt,

If Ajax is used there is no need to use html-->input-->submit. Use a `<button>` tag 
 and then invoke the js function.